# R does not recognize quadratic function in model formula?

Tags: r

Really simple question, I'm working through Pinheiro and Bates (nlme) on page 42 using the Pixel dataset.

```r
library (nlme)

fm1Pixel <- lme(pixel ~ day + day^2, data=Pixel, random = list(Dog = ~ day, Side = ~ 1))
```

Looks straightforward enough, but the output simply does not recognise existence of `day^2`:

```r
intervals (fm1Pixel)
Approximate 95% confidence intervals

Fixed effects
                lower         est.        upper

(Intercept) 1071.415261 1093.2153217 1115.0153825

day           -1.126045   -0.1486644    0.8287158

attr(,"label")

[1] "Fixed effects:"...
```

It works fine if I manually create a `^2` variable, but the model itself (also with simple `lm()`) does not recognise `^2`...

Anyone else with the same problem?

Am I typing something wrongly?

Grateful for your help,

Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your transformations in a `I()` element, like that:

```r
 lme (pixel ~ day + I(day^2), data=Pixel, random = list(Dog = ~ day, Side = ~ 1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your super fast response! The book was written for S and I didn't appreciate the subtlety.